# Creating an array of pointers to struct

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct

I am having trouble of understanding how to create an array of pointers to structures. I tried to look up similar examples and threads in the forum but I still cannot get my code to work! As a result, I believe I have written an ugly piece of code that I do not know where it is wrong and how to fix it.
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Movie
    {
       string name;
       int numawards;
       int nomination;
       int year;
    };

void *readfile(ifstream &infile, int &n);

int main()
{
    ifstream infile;
    int n = 0;
    infile.open("old_movies.txt");
    Movie *oldmovies;
    oldmovies = readfile (infile, n);

    return 0;

}
//*function documentation//
void *readfile (ifstream &infile, int &n)
{

    infile >> n;
    Movie *movies;
    movies = new Movie[n];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        infile >> movies[i]->year >> movies[i]->numawards >> movies[i]->nomination;
        infile.ignore();
        infile.ignore();
        getline(infile, movies[i]->name);

        cout << movies[i]->year << " " << movies[i]->numawards << " " << movies[i]->nomination << " " << endl << movies[i]->name<< endl; //the cout here is to test and see if the code works.
    }
    return movies;
}
```

The purpose of this code is to read a txt file that contains the movie name, how many awards, how may nominations, and what year it is produced, and then print it out using pointers. Here is what the file looks like:

```
2
1935 1 3

The Dark Angel

1935 4 6

The Informer

1935 1 8
```

the first 4 digits represents the year, the second one represents number of awards it has gotten, and the last digit represents the number of times it has been nominated to an award.

Anyway, I am stuck at this part and I am really clueless about what to do here. I just hope that this code is not that bad to a point where there are numerous things to be changed. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You declare `Movie *oldmovies;` but populate the array using the assignment `oldmovies = readfile (infile, n);`, yet the function has the signature `void *readfile (ifstream &infile, int &n)`. It is declared to return `void`, but you try to `return movies` at the end of the function.

Comment: Consider defining functions before you use them. Advantage: No need for forward-declarations. Also, don't take an `ifstream&`-argument where an `istream&` suffices (And check you actually succeeded reading *before* you use the read value). Next, avoid `using namespace std;`, though at least it's not in a header. Finally, the `return 0;` in `main` is superfluous.

Comment: Addendum: Avoid over-long lines, especially when posting on the internet. 80 characters is more than enough.

Comment: @Deduplicator Thanks for the advice! and I actually checked and the file before I assigned pointers and the file was read correctly. As for using namespace std; and return 0;, I really have no choice but to put it there as my professor docks point off for not using it.

Comment: @CowEatsGrass: We are feeling with you. The establishment often has too long-established habits, that always hurts. Can you get him to justify it, or is it just "that's what I do"? Regarding checking successful reading: Where do you test that you successfully read on the first line of `readfile`?

Comment: @Deduplicator So i read the file first before I create the pointers. So basically, To check it, I would remove all the " * " and replace the -> operators with . operator. Yes, I did not write a code that tests whether or not the file was read successfully or not, but I did start creating these pointers after I made the files being correctly opened, which was printing out the results.

Comment: Just replace `infile >> n;` with `if(!(infile>>n)) {n=0;return 0;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at what you have here:

```
Movie *movies;
movies = new Movie[n];
```

This allocates an array of `Movie` instances. To allocate an array of pointers dynamically, you need to change this to

```
Movie** movies;
movies = new Movie*[n];
```

Now inside the for loop, you need to allocate each `Movie` instance:

```
movies[i] = new Movie();
```

You should also change the `readfile()` to return a `Movie**` rather than a `void*` so that you don't have to use any casts later.

But do you really need an array of pointers? Why not just use an array of structs. This would avoid the extra level of indirection and make your code a little simpler.

Comment: Yea i really do as this assignment's required for me to use pointers. If I have the option of not using pointers, I would have not used it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: and the second before the last sentence, you said "change readfile() to return a Movie**..." Can you explain it more since I am still a noob in this area so I am quite confused here.

Comment: @CowEatsGrass "use pointers" isn't the same as "use an array of pointers"

Comment: sorry I am not using the terms correctly(because they all seem so similar to me). Yes, I need to use "an array of pointers", not "pointers". Thanks for pointing out my mistake at wording.